# Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED is showing error in npm console

Tags: android, firebase, ionic3

```
    Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
```

I also added the android:exported="false" in the AndroidManifest.xml file

I have already added the android:exported="false" in the AndroidManifest.xml file in

Comment: You solve this issue?

Comment: Yes @LuiscYm the push plugin is the problem. So I have added the android:exported="false" manual to the plugin.xml and other files and the problem get solved.